# Prototypejs observe function throws error

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this line of code but it throws an error.  What is the problem with the code?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://prototypejs.org/javascripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            Event.observe('target', 'click', function(event) {
                // ...
            });

        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='target'>Click me!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try the answer i posted. It  works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the script after your

tag is loaded. This way you dont need to detect the dom:loaded event. :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://prototypejs.org/javascripts/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='target'>Click me!</p>
          <script type="text/javascript">

                Event.observe('target', 'click', function(event) {
                    alert('clicked me');
                });

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually up voting is not a bad idea if the solution helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to bind the event handler to does not exist in the DOM at the time your code is executed. Wrap it in a DOM ready event handler:

```js
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    Event.observe('target', 'click', function(event) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

This is mentioned in the [Prototype docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/):

> One of the most common errors trying to observe events is trying to do
>   it before the element exists in the DOM. Don't try to observe elements
>   until after the dom:loaded event or window load event has been fired.

Comment: @user1077300 - Can you make an example on http://jsfiddle.net? And what error do you get?

Comment: Jsfiddle.net might not be good for testing because it sill doesnt require dom:loaded event , as it loads the scripts after the html!

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala - You have to set the include point to "no wrap (head)". Then it includes the JS in the same place the OP has done in the question.

Comment: @JamesAllardice, ah, good to know. btw , its better to load the script at the bottom of the page to get this working!(in a way its still waiting for dom:load as well.)